# Convert NSString to NSDate to compare which one is newer?

Tags: objective-c, date, compare, nsdate, nsdateformatter

First time caller, long time listener :)   Love this site.  I'm new to Objective-C but have a blast learning.  I'm sorry for such a simple question but I can't figure this out.  :(

I have two NSStrings in the format: 
itemdate: [March 1, 2013] lastloaddate: [January 1, 1980]

I want to find out which string (date) is most recent.  To do this I'm trying to convert the NSString to NSDate and then do a compare but i'm not having any luck.  Here is my code.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *titemdate = [df dateFromString: itemdate];

NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *tlasttimerundate = [df1 dateFromString: lastdate];

if ([tlasttimerundate compare:titemdate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
   NSLog(@"itemdate is newer than lastdate");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM d,YYYY"];` instead of `[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];`

The `MMMM` format will get the full date month where as the `MM` format will just the months number. For example `MM` is `5` and `MMMMM` is `May`.

To achieve the date compare:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM d,YYYY"];
df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
NSDate *titemdate = [df dateFromString: itemdate];
NSDate *tlasttimerundate = [df dateFromString: lastdate];

if ([tlasttimerundate compare:titemdate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
   NSLog(@"itemdate is newer than lastdate");
}
```

---

You can find more about the date formats here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I would like to suggest that you also tell `NSDateFormatter` the locale for the date: `df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];`. Other which if the iOS system language is not set to english it will not be able to parse the date.

Comment: Yeah true.Will include that in my answer

Comment: Still does not work.  using your code I get nothing in the output window. :(   When I do a:

NSLog(@"Podcast date: [%@] lastdate: [%@]", itemdate, lastdate);

I receive: Podcast date: [May 10, 2013] lastdate: [January 1, 1980]

so I'm pretty sure my strings are correct.  I'm perplexed. :(

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @rckoenes : hehe we were editing it parallely i changed the date format to mmmm and when about to submit your edit appears !!! :)

Comment: ah... one more thing.  I need to use 'NSOrderedAscending' in order to see if itemdate is newer than lastdate!  This one works for me Descending does not. 

Thank you so much for your help!! you guys ROCK!

Comment: @LithuT.V saw that as well :D was just changing the date format because I spotted the error there.